# Fade In/Fade out a series of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page in which text appears in the center of the screen, fades out and is replaced by other text. I have tried various approaches, but if I am successful in fading out the divs, they disappear too quickly. Other times it doesn't iterate through my for-loop correctly.

I understand that there are other similar questions, but the solutions there haven't helped me make much progress.

I have successfully determined how to fade in the elements. I am using jQuery version 3.2.1

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="hidden1">
     <h1> Some text </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden2">
     <h1> Other Text </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden3">
    <h1> Even more text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my css

```
.hidden1, .hidden2, .hidden3 {
   opacity : 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   position: fixed;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Here is my JS

```
var elements = ['hidden1', 'hidden2', 'hidden3'];

for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      var thisElement = $("." + elements[i]); //get the current element based on class
      fadeInElement(thisElement, i); //call fade in function
      setTimeout(function() {
            $(thisElement).fadeOut(1000);
        }, 1000);
}
function fadeInElement(elem, time){
   setTimeout(function() {
      elem.css("opacity", "1"); //set element's opacity to 1
    }, 1250 * time); //set the time it should wait
}
```

You can see a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/5tfaqvbg/1/

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/5tfaqvbg/4/

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to build.

Comment: @ChrisG can you create an answer? I'll delete mine and accept yours!

Comment: Done, see below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do this with jQuery selectors, `.css()` and a transition:

```js
var $elements = $('.hidden');

$elements.each(function(i) {
  let el = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(el).css("opacity", 1);
  }, 1500 * i);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(el).css("opacity", 0);
  }, 1500 * (i + 1));
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h1>
      Some text
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h1>
      Other Text
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h1>
      Even more text
    </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Was this something you were going for?

```js
var elements = ['hidden1', 'hidden2', 'hidden3'];

for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      var thisElement = $("." + elements[i]); //get the current element based on class
      fadeInElement(thisElement, i); //call fade in function
      thisElement.fadeOut();
}
function fadeInElement(elem, time){
   setTimeout(function() {
          elem.fadeIn();
    }, 1250 * time); //set the time it should wait
}
```

```css
.hidden1 .hidden2, .hidden 3{
   opacity : 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   position: fixed;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="hidden1">
     <h1> Some text </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden2">
     <h1> Other Text </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden3">
    <h1> Even more text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: When I tried this, the text didn't appear at all. I had tried something similar to this earlier, but the transition between fading in and fading out just kept happening too quickly. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @genhernandez You can also specify a time in the `.fadeOut()` or `.fadeIn()`. Say you want it to take one second, you can use `.fadeOut(1000)` or `.fadeIn(1000)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `opacity:0` to other elements as well.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var elements = ['hidden1', 'hidden2', 'hidden3'];

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("." + elements[i]).css("opacity", "1");
  }, 1000 * i);
  if (i < (elements.length - 1)) { //for displaying the last element
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + elements[i]).css("opacity", "0");
    }, 1000 * (i + 1));
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden1,
.hidden2,
.hidden3 {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="hidden1">
    <h1>Some text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden2">
    <h1>Other Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden3">
    <h1>Even more text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/5tfaqvbg/11/)**